# PHP Class Dependency Injection Failure

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

Okay, I've often had some unsolved errors when it comes to accessing several other classes in one class.
Depending on which class gets required first, it will not make it accessible in the **__construct** function in the other files.

```
Undefined property: Container::$Core in /usr/share/nginx/html/app/classes/class.users.php on line 9
```

**class.container.php**

```
public function __construct() {
    if(isset(self::$class)) {
        foreach(self::$class as $key => $value) {
            if(!isset($this->{$key})) {
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
    }   
} 

public function setClassHandlers($class = []) {
            if(!isset(self::$class)) {
                foreach($class as $name => $file) {
                    $file = DIR . "app/classes/" . $file;

                    if(!isset(self::$library[$name])) {
                        // Get interface file
                        $interface = DIR . "app/classes/interfaces/interface.".strtolower($name).".php";
                        // Check if interface file exists
                        if(!file_exists($interface)) {
                            // Throw exception
                            $this->throwException("Unable to load interface file: {$interface}");
                        }

                        // Require interface
                        require_once $interface;
                        //Check if interface is set
                        if(!interface_exists("i".ucfirst($name))) {
                            // Throw exception
                            $this->throwException("Unable to find interface: {$interface}");
                        }

                        // Check if class file exists
                        if(!file_exists($file)) {
                            // Throw exception
                            $this->throwException("Unable to load class file: {$file}");
                        }
                        // Require class
                        require_once $file;
                        // Check if class file exists
                        if(class_exists($name)) {
                            // Set Library
                            self::$library[$name] = $file;
                            // Set interface
                            self::$interface[$name] = $interface;
                            // Set class        // class.container.php
                            self::$class[$name] = new $name(new self);
                            $this->{$name} = self::$class[$name];
                        } else {
                            // Thror error
                            $this->throwException("Unable to load class: {$name}", self::$library[$name]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            } 
        }
```

Inserting arguments into the function on **index.php**:

```
require_once DIR . 'app/management/dependency.php';

$container = new Container();

$container->setClassHandlers([
    // Name         // Path
    'Database'  => 'class.database.php',
    'Config'    => 'class.config.php',
    'Users'     => 'class.users.php',
    'Core'      => 'class.core.php',
    //'Admin'       => 'class.admin.php',
    //'Forum'       => 'class.forum.php',
    //'Template'    => 'class.template.php'
]);
```

**class.users.php**

```
public function __construct(Container $class) {
        $this->db   = $class->Database;
        $this->core = $class->Core;
        $this->ip   = $this->core->userIP();
        $this->container = $class;
    }
```

For example both **Users** and **Core** are used within the same file of eachother, but as mentioned above, if **Core** gets required first, **Users** is not an available dependency inside that class.
I'm not really quite sure how to fix this, so every help is appreciated.

Comment: are you aware this is wrong? or is it a typo on your question?`$file = DIR . "app/classes/" . $file;` It should be `__DIR__`

Comment: @yivi not really a typo when "DIR" is defined as `dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, but whats the difference between that and `__DIR__`?

Comment: `__DIR__` is magic constant, similar to `__FILE__`.  Always points to the dir where the current file is. For clarity sake, wouldn't advise on using `DIR`. Use `WEBROOT` or something more explicit, IMO. native `__DIR__` doesn't include trailing slash though.

Comment: You are kind reinventing the wheel, but poorly I'm afraid. Any reason why you don't want to use an existing container, such as [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/), that's simple and lightweight?

Comment: @yivi I'd rather learn it myself than using others work.

Comment: @yivi but this is pretty irrelevant due to the actual subject on how I fix this annoying error

Comment: Don't take it wrong, I want to help. I'll post a bit of code in a minute. But it appears to me that you are trying stuff you don't fully understand yet. By using and exploring other's work, you may profit greatly and learn much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "container" is trying to instantiate the contained objects when the setClassHandlers method is run, and by that time not all its properties might be set.

Also, your container is not "lazy" enough. is trying to instantiate everything **right now**, even if it might not be needed.

Try the following

First, remove these lines:

```
    // Set class        // class.container.php
    self::$class[$name] = new $name(new self);
    $this->{$name} = self::$class[$name];
```

Then, add a private array services to your Container class:

```
private $services = [];
```

And finally, add a magic getter to your container:

```
function __get($service)
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->services[$service]) ) {
            $this->services[$service] = new $service();
        }

        return $this->services[$service];
    }
```

Again, learning about this is **great**, but I would advise you take a look at some other implementations to learn from them. [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/)'s is great, very simple, and easy to follow.

Here we are injecting the container on all your objects instead of the object concrete dependencies, which is generally (an rightly) frowned up upon. But I don't want to introduce more modifications to your design, is better that you learn those by yourself.

On top of that, your container is also handling what would be better handled by an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), and mixing responsibilities.

Also, as I said in the comments, you are reinventing the `__DIR__` constant, which already exists in PHP. You are using

```
define( 'DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );
```

which is pretty much equivalent to `__DIR__` (Or, more precisely, to `__DIR__ . '/'`).

---

Finally, most of your troubles are caused by circular dependencies, which your container (nor any container) can't fix. A depends on B which depends on A. The only way you could get around that is by using a setter to inject your dependencies.

A simpler implementation, more or less following your code:

For autoloading:

```
function autoload_so($class)
{
    $file = __DIR__ . "/app/classes/class." . strtolower($class) . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once($file);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_so');
```

I'm not using namespaces, and I disregarded your interface logic. Which was a bit weird as well. You'll need to implement your own loading for interfaces, you should be able to do so.

For the container:

```
class MyContainer
{
    public $services = [];

    function __get($service)
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->services[$service]) ) {
            $this->services[$service] = call_user_func([$this, "get_$service"]);
        }

        return $this->services[$service];
    }

    /**
     * @return Users
     */
    private function get_Users()
    {
        return new Users($this->Database, $this->Core);
    }

    /**
     * @return Core
     */
    private function get_Core()
    {
        return new Core();
    }

    /**
     * @return Database
     */
    private function get_Database()
    {
        return new Database($this->Core);
    }

}
```

Notice that

- You'll need a new method for each new "service" you want to add.
- I'm injecting the dependencies directly in the constructor

Finally your classes would be something like:

Database

```
<?php

class Database
{
    public function __construct(Core $core)
    {
        $this->core  = $core;
    }
}
```

Users

```
class Users
{
    public $ip;

    public function __construct(Database $db, Core $core)
    {
        $this->db   = $db;
        $this->core = $core;
        $this->ip   = $this->core->userIP();
    }

}
```

etc.

Again, this is all very crude. I would use namespaces and a more general autoloader and directory structure.

All this should be enough for a starting point for you to build your own.

But **no container will magically fix your circular dependencies for you**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will see if this would work and otherwise check out Pimple, because it looks useful

Comment: Cool. Let me know how it goes with this, ok? If it doesn't work we can revisit the code. :)

Comment: I receive this error when trying to call **userIP()** function from **class.core.php** on my index page: `Call to undefined Closure::userIP()`

Comment: Okay it worked at first, but now I'm still receving the undefined property error :/

Comment: Where, specifically?

Comment: The same as before :/

Comment: `Undefined property: Container::$Core`: this one?

Comment: Aaargh. Yup, now that I go over it more slowly, I see it. Your container is a bit of a mess. Can't really debug here. I'll update you this afternoon when I get home.

Comment: Updated the question since I totally forgot to add a **__construct** function which is set inside the container file.

Comment: Maybe spl_autoload_register would do the work? If I read correctly, it only initiates the classes, but I still would receive the same error due to the order of classes being required, or am I mistaken about this?

Comment: the autoloader part of what you are missing. I'm writing a simple container now.

Comment: I'll put together a simpler container + spl_autloader. Very crude, but functional. Still, wont resolve your problem until you resolve a more basic problem with your code: you have circular dependencies. Users depends on Database. Database depends on Users. That won't do.

Comment: yeah, but dunno how to fix it, because both classes have functions inside used by one another

Comment: I've seen your updated answer, and lets say I'd decide to use Pimple, could it get around making a new function for each class that needs to be loaded, and without defining the type-hint as the classes required?

Comment: I've thought about it, and if your answer doesn't work as I want it too, I might check out PHP-DI and Redis.

Comment: What is the difference between injecting something using __construct or extend the class? Because I found a solution that worked, but only if I extended the class and not injecting it using __construct.

Comment: inheritance and DI are different concepts, and solve different problems. You are mixing up things.